# Code to find the existence of file with partial filename

Tags: c#

I have a file as c:\sai\chn_20151019_5932.txt . Here 5932 is minutes and seconds format. 59 mins 32 secs. When we run again the package on the same day the existed file in the folder should deleted but , due to the seconds I am unable to delete the file. 
I need C# code something like this.

```
steing filename: @"c:\sai\chn_20151019_5932.txt";        
if(filename.exists(@"c:\sai\chn_20151019" + "*")               
{               
   delete.file(filename);               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using .NET or above -

```
string path = @"c:\sai";
bool exist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "chn_20151019*").Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\sai\");

foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("chn_20151019*.txt")) {
    file.Delete();
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\sai\");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("chn_20151019*.txt")
                     .Where(p => p.Extension == ".txt").ToArray();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    try
    {
        File.Delete(file.FullName);
    }
    catch { }
```

Comment: enumeratefiles method can be used only after .net 4.0, but I need the code for .net 3.5 framework version. Can you please give an alternate code

Comment: @SAILENDRASUDA:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EnumerateFiles` which will find files by pattern in specified directory. And then just use File.Delete

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\sai","chn_20151019*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(x=>File.Delete(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `using System.IO;`, then:

```
foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\sai\", "chn_20151019*.txt"))
{
    File.Delete(f);
}
```

If you like to be fancy (`using System;`):

```
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\sai\", "chn_20151019*.txt"), File.Delete);
```